# facebook Web form login using HttpWebRequest (c#)

Tags: c#, facebook, httpwebrequest

Im getting stuck with my code. Im just trying to access facebook home via c# and httpweb request.

I'm trying to do the login stuff with:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
string s = "email=XXXXX@mymail.com&pass=YYYYY";

CookieContainer cookies = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

request.Method = "POST";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Timeout = 10000;
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.ContentLength = s.Length;

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

System.IO.Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();

Console.WriteLine("\n Cookies count is :{0}", cookies.Count); //0, obviously
//get response and print it

System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream response_stream = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response_stream);
string response_string = sr.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine("\n Cookies count is :{0}", cookies.Count);
```

OK. At this point two things happened:

1. I have 3 cookies stored (cookies.count)
2. HTML response from FB says that I need to activate cookies in my browser.

My questions are:

1. Is the code above correct? If so, why am I getting the cookie message from FB?
2. If I now want to navigate to my FB home, should I create another request to home URL using the cookies store filled previously?

Answer (score 1):

Solved now, thanks.

The problems was a malformed string used to perform the login POST form. Be sure to include the exact params + values as in original web form.

;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read something from Facebook maybe its better to use facebook api to do that. There is a project [Facebook c# SDK on codeplex,](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) it could be handy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, i knew about the FB sdk but it's not what im looking for. Id like to build an app to check info directly from the web. Thanks again.